# How do I insert $data and $param into body of email

Tags: javascript, email, phprunner

I am not a programmer and using phprunner to create page to send an email to selected records.
I have used some pre-existing code via this link
https://phprunner.com/phprunner/docs/email_selected_users.htm
and a modification to it on stackoverflow (Thanks [Micheal.M][1]).  I need to input the 'from' 'subject' and 'body' via a form. The 'subject' and 'from' parts works fine.

But how can I get the $params["emailBody"] and the $data["FirstName"] both to appear in the 'body' of the email?
'FirstName' field is from a table called Students_ALL.

Can someone please guide me? I have tried for two days and cannot figure it out. Please find the code below: THANK YOU SO MUCH in advance - Mayo

SERVER

```
if( $params["emailBody"] ||$params["emailSubject"] || $params["emailFrom"] )
{
$emails = array();

while( $data = $button->getNextSelectedRecord() )
{
    // Send only if email field not empty
    if( $data["Email1"] ) {
        // This no longer should be an array of emails
                $from = $params["emailFrom"];
       $email = $data["Email1"];
                $subject = $params["emailSubject"];
                $body = $params ["emailBody"];
        // Email will be sent for each record
        $arr = runner_mail(array('to' => $email, 'subject' => $subject, 'from' => $from, 'htmlbody' => $body));
}
}

$result["txt"] = "Emails were sent.";
if (!$arr["mailed"])
{
$errmsg = "Error happened:
";
$errmsg.= "File: " . $arr["errors"][0]["file"] . "
";
$errmsg.= "Line: " . $arr["errors"][0]["line"] . "
";
$errmsg.= "Description: " . $arr["errors"][0]["description"] . "
";
$result["txt"] = $errmsg;
}
}
```

### CLIENT BEFORE

```
if ( proxy["emailUsers"] === true ) {  
   params["emailFrom"] = proxy["emailFrom"];
   params["emailBody"] = proxy["emailBody"];
   params["emailSubject"] = proxy["emailSubject"];
 
   proxy["emailUsers"] = false;
  return true;
}  
 
var selBoxes = pageObj.getSelBoxes( pageid ),
   args = {
       modal: true,
       header: "Input from, subject and body",
       html: '<div>'
          + '<div>From: <input type="text" id="emailFrom"s style="margin: 5px 0"></div>'
          + '<div>Subject: <input type="text" id="emailSubject"s style="margin: 5px 0"></div>'
          + '<div>Body: <textarea id="emailBody"></textarea></div>'
          + '</div>',
       footer: '<a href="#" id="emailUsersSave" class="btn btn-primary">' + Runner.lang.constants.TEXT_SAVE + '</a>'
           + '<a href="#" id="emailUsersCancel" class="btn btn-default">' + Runner.lang.constants.TEXT_CANCEL + '</a>',
       afterCreate: function( win ) {
          $("#emailUsersSave").on("click", function( e ) {
              var context = win.body();
 
               proxy["emailUsers"] = true;
               proxy["emailFrom"] = $("#emailFrom", context).val();
               proxy["emailBody"] = $("#emailBody", context).val();
               proxy["emailSubject"] = $("#emailSubject", context).val();
              $('[id="' + ctrl.id + '"]').click();
 
               e.preventDefault();              
               win.destroy();
           });
 
          $("#emailUsersCancel").on("click", function( e ) {
               e.preventDefault();
               win.destroy();                        
           });        
       }
   };
 
if ( selBoxes.length == 0 || !confirm('Do you really want to email these records?') ) {
  return false;
}
 
Runner.displayPopup( args );
return false;
```

### CLIENT AFTER

```
var message = result["txt"] + " !!!";
ctrl.setMessage(message);

 [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2432106/michal-m
```